# Creating modules/HMVC in sails.js

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, area, sails.js, separation-of-concerns

I am trying to make a separation in my new SailsJS app by creating modules/HMVC, just like ASP.NET MVC, and Codeigniter PHP. These frameworks provide a mechanism for handling such a separation. Do any one have an idea how to implement this in SailsJS?

Comment: Are you asking about views or client-side MVC frameworks? or both?

Comment: I am asking about the server-side MVC implemented by SailsJS. So if you have worked with other MVC frameworks in both dot net and php they provide a way to separate things logically.

Comment: you're talking about modules, HMVC is what its called on the php side usually.. MVC grouped by function right?

Comment: I would say yes, my question is about HMVC principle

Answer (score 1):

There is some development taking place in that direction, I'm not quite sure whether or not anything usable already exists, at least I haven't been able to find anything final so far. Two threads where adding HMVC to sails was discussed are

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1191

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/594

Answer (score 0):

I think the most recent sails plugin/backend components system discussion is [balderdashy/sails/pull/2083](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2083).

It looks like the most viable module solution today is [balderdashy/sails-hook-subapps](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-subapps), an example of a [sails hook](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks). Hopefully, it works with 0.12.x and gets some attention/docs soon!

Additionally, the project [sailorjs/sailorjs](https://github.com/sailorjs/sailorjs) appears to do exactly this as a fork of sails from version 0.10.x, though I don't know if there are plans ot utilize that work in sails.js.